# PHP English Dictionary

Tags: php, performance, spell-checking

I'm taking cross-referencing arbitrary text (20K+) through a MySQL WordNet database; very slow.

The virtual host I'm on support Pspell but not Aspell. They won't install new DSOs and don't allow access to CLI.

I can't use a web service because the load will be too heavy.

So is their any alternative, should I just load a txt file up and let her rip lol

Answer (score 1):

English is a lot more than spelling. When I talk like Yoda: "Crazy, is what you are" then there is no misspelling, but not the Queens English either. AFAIK that is not gonna work!

However, if you ensist to go this path, have a look at Lucene.

Comment: You're right, there's part of speech too. I'm not trying to block, but trying to encourage. Then there's the other "encouragement strategies" keyword density spam checking, the range of the automated readability index and flesch kincaid grade level, etc, etc,.